# fft formula convention

Tags: fft, numpy

I try to code up an algorithm from a scientific paper where they solve a differential equation using Fourier transforms. In the paper, they use the FT convention $\rho(x_i) = \sum_{k=-m}^m r_k e^{i2\pi kx_i} $, where $x_i$ is the ith data point.

Numpy uses the convention described in the  [`fft` routine documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html).

Both of these should be completely equivalent (the negative $k$ in one convention correspond to the highest $k$ in the other convention).

Now, in the paper they frequently multiply $r_k$ with a function that depends on this $k$, i.e. $r_k f(k)$.
This should be the same as if I wrote $A_k\cdot f(k)$ in Numpy's convention. And the $A_k$ are simply given by `A[k]` if `A=numpy.fft(ρ, N)`.
Is this correct?

I was confused by the statement

> and A[n/2+1:] contains the negative-frequency terms

But this simply refers back to the other convention and should not change anything in the way I calculate $A_k\cdot f(k)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi! check your formula please. It uses $\rho$ on both sides ?

Comment: Sorry, the $\rho_k^*$ is supposed to be the fourier amplitude. I should not have used the $*$ symbol. So left is $\rho$ in real space, right is in $k$ space.

Comment: please edit the question to reflect the change...

Comment: better like this

Comment: sorry but still not better. what's $x_i$ and whay cannot you use another letter for $\rho$ in one of the sides ???

Comment: ok like this now?